# can i use 2 setScene on graphicsView?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

i use this code but graphicsView will show the last command, 
how can i show two setScence in one graphicsView?

```
ui->setupUi(this);
line1= new QGraphicsScene (this);
line= new QGraphicsScene (this);

ui->graphicsView->setScene(line);    // not show
ui->graphicsView->setScene(line1);   // show
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two QGraphicsViews. QGraphicsView can only show one scene at a time. I'm not sure it would make sense any other way. Perhaps you can look to [QLayout](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlayout.html) or [QSplitter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsplitter.html) if you want the two scenes/views side-by-side.